# Reading all data from every rows in data process using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to process a set of data for merging purposes. Before the merging, There were some processes. as I have a separated date and time column along with a secondary combined datetime column which I have to match the closest time between this both set of datetime using merge_asof. Prior to that, I will require to capture the 1st and last timestamp of the 1st set of datetime to use as the time boundary for the 2nd set of data. to achieve this, I converted the datetime to unix timestamp for comparison. As the 2 sets of datetime do not have equal number of values(e.g. 1st datetime set have data up to 20 rows while 2nd datetime have up to 50 rows). I only manage to cut the datetime of 2nd set up till the 20th row as there is no datetime for 1st set of data on the 21st row onwards.

The data are like :

```
Date,Arr,Qdate
7/10/2011,6:05:04,7/10/2011  12:02:57 AM
7/10/2011,6:12:16,7/10/2011  6:09:41 AM
7/10/2011,6:18:00,7/10/2011  6:12:27 AM
7/10/2011,19:34:47,7/10/2011  7:02:04 PM
7/10/2011,19:52:21,7/10/2011  7:29:20 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:34:53 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:41:35 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:52:23 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:58:21 PM
,,7/10/2011  8:01:22 PM
```

After doing the processing, it successfully restrict the time frame to the 1st and last date time using the code below

```
mydataset = pd.read_csv(x + ".csv", error_bad_lines=False, engine ='python', index_col= False,header = 0, sep = ",")
mydataset['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['Date'] + ' ' + mydataset['Arr'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')  
mydataset['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['Qdate'] , format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='ignore')
mydataset['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['Date2'])
mydataset = mydataset[mydataset['Date1'].notnull()]
mydataset['tsArrTime'] = mydataset['Date1'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()))                                     #conversion of unix timestamp
mydataset['tsTTime'] = mydataset['Date2'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()) if str(x) != 'NaT' else 0)             #conversion of unix timestamp
minTime = mydataset['tsArrTime'].min()                                                                                      
maxTime = mydataset['tsArrTime'].max() + 60                                                                                 
mydataset.loc[(mydataset['tsTTime'] < minTime) | (mydataset['tsTTime'] > maxTime), 'Qdate'] = ''                           
mydataset.loc[(mydataset['tsTTime'] < minTime) | (mydataset['tsTTime'] > maxTime), 'VID'] = ''                              
mydataset = mydataset.drop(columns=['Date1','Date2','tsArrTime','tsTTime'])
```

This was the result:

```
Date,Arr,Qdate
7/10/2011,6:05:04,
7/10/2011,6:12:16,7/10/2011  6:09:41 AM
7/10/2011,6:18:00,7/10/2011  6:12:27 AM
7/10/2011,19:34:47,7/10/2011  7:02:04 PM
7/10/2011,19:52:21,7/10/2011  7:29:20 PM
```

But there are some data missing so I would like to achieve this

```
Date,Arr,Qdate
7/10/2011,6:05:04,
7/10/2011,6:12:16,7/10/2011  6:09:41 AM
7/10/2011,6:18:00,7/10/2011  6:12:27 AM
7/10/2011,19:34:47,7/10/2011  7:02:04 PM
7/10/2011,19:52:21,7/10/2011  7:29:20 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:34:53 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:41:35 PM
,,7/10/2011  7:52:23 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by separating the data into 2 different data set to do the time boundary process then doing a merge

```
mydataset1 = mydataset[mydataset['Date1'].notnull()]
mydataset2 = mydataset.Date2
print(mydataset1)
print(mydataset2)
tsArrTime = mydataset1.Date1.apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()))                                     #conversion of unix timestamp
tsTTime = mydataset2.apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()))             #conversion of unix timestamp
minTime = tsArrTime.min()                                                                                      
maxTime = tsArrTime.max() + 60                                                                                 
print(tsArrTime)
print(tsTTime)
mydataset.loc[(tsTTime < minTime) | (tsTTime > maxTime), 'Qdate'] = ''                            
mydataset.loc[(tsTTime < minTime) | (tsTTime > maxTime), 'VID'] = ''
```